# Adding gdst (Guided Decision Tables) programmatically

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

While there are ways to [add DRL rules programmatically](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=drools%20add%20rules%20programmatically), could not find if it is possible to add "Guided Decision Table" programmatically. These rules are visible in WebDAV as gdst files are just XML. Are there API to create these rules without the guvnor UI, upload to guvnor using WebDAV or REST and use the UI later to make changes?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out yet?  I need to do the same thing.

Comment: No luck. I posted in the drools forum too - no response. One way I could see was the gdst is XML. So possibly we can create the file and upload with REST or WebDAV. But need the XML definition.

Comment: thanks, I'll let you know if I find something.

Comment: same here .. i need to do the same thing. :)

Comment: Take a look at this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378587/compile-drools-guided-decision-table-into-rules

Answer (score 0):

You can add/move/update gdst via Drools WB internal GIT :)
Fisrt of all, you need have a look to the documentation about configuration/properties / and stay on WB 6.2.0-beta2 (don't go to beta3 or CR1).

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.CR1/drools-docs/html/wb.Workbench.html#wb.systemProperties

Please note :

1. default host is localhost so you yoou need to change this with

   org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.host
2. move default git dir, M2 repo to some exteral path to Jboss AS.

Finally, you'll notice that only 'edited' files are shered through GIT / not the 'generated ones.
So if you are focused on .gdst, you'll not be able to retrieve/edit the generated .drl you can see in WB.

Good luck :)

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378587/compile-drools-guided-decision-table-into-rules